# What is add2 for sortfields

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

When I use the macro recorder on sorting a ListObject (table), it produces:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").ListObjects("Table4").Sort.SortFields.Add2
```

which works perfectly fine in my version of Excel. However, this doesn't compile on other Excels. Changing it to `.Add` solves the problem.

Google says that `.Add2` only exists for ChartObjects - but the recorder records it for a ListObject - and it works here but not in the other Excel (same version).

What is `.Add2`? Why does my Excel think that's the correct way?

Comment: Could the chart collection not exist on other Excels you are running this line on?

Comment: @EdwinEderle Perhaps you should describe what you wanted your recorded Macro to do instead of wondering, what `Add2` does.  The best answer  you can hope for is a transcription of the best google result you could find yourself, probably jacked straight from MDN

Comment: Very easy - i have a listobject (a tabl) that i need to sort. Google says that add2 only exists for chartobjects - but the recorder records it for a table - and it works here but not in the other Excel (same version). Manually changing it to add solves it.
I still would love to better understand this

Comment: @EdwinEderle So it does not work on other Excel files with your Excel version - even on a `ListObject`?

Comment: I have not tried the code on other Excel files, but this Excel file does not compile on other computers with the same Excel version - so my Excel installation thinks it can run (and record) this even for listobjects

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer; I'd like to add what I found out. Should have used comment maybe (but unable to).

- I can **confirm** Excel 365 Business macro recorder records `Sort.SortFields.Add2` if you define a filter on either a ListObject or a Worksheet.
- I can **not** confirm the macro does not work on same Excel version on another machine (for me it works; tested with Excel 16.0.10228.20080 32Bit).
- The `Add2` method is not documented on MSDN for the `SortFields` Collection ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sortfields-object-excel)), but for serveral other objects (so "only for ChartObject" is not corrrect).
- The VBA object library (of my Excel version, see above) lists `Add2` as Function in `SortFields` Class; the only difference between `Add` and `Add2` seems to be that `Add2` has one more optional paramter `[SubField]`.

**Conclusion**: I guess (but this is only a guess!) that `Add2` to is an expansion in functionality that has been implemented with a new name for compatibility reasons. Maybe the macro recorder always uses the most recent function in such a case.
Yor can use `Add` unless you need the `SubField` parameter.

I still like to get a deeper understanding, like Edwin Ederle asked for. I came across this post because of exact the same situation: using the recorder to learn about coding sort functions, wondering about `Add2`, and asking google. This question is (one of) the first google hit(s) if you search for "vba sortfields add2" => maybe worth giving some more information here.

Answer (score 2):

`Add2` is a method on SortFields only available in newer versions of Excel.  The difference to `Add` is that `Add2` supports a subfield parameter.  For example in a geography field you can sort by population.

The macro recorder uses `Add2` to support sorting by subfields.  If you don't need to sort by subfields then you can change the recorded code to `Add` and it will work on older versions of Excel.