# .Add2 generates Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2016

I'm receiving the following error:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

with the following code

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend 3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal"
```

This error is coming in one laptop, whereas in another system, I am not facing any issue. In both the systems, it is 2016 version.

This is the rest of my code:

```
Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Backend 3").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend 3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend 3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend 3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:A1001")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Sheets("Backend 3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Backend 2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Range("E11").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Not clear where [SortFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields) `Add2` method shall coming from.

Comment: @AxelRichter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Yes, but it will not work always: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148316/what-is-add2-for-sortfields.

Comment: Axel IMHO it will work in Office 2016 (365) and not on any versions lower than that

Comment: Does not work in my Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4738.1000) 32-Bit

Comment: And you tried it with a listobject? If yes then it is really surprising. MS-office is updated?

Comment: Maybe it is a language version issue. My Excel 2016 is a German one. And my Macro recorder always records `SortFields.Add` and never `SortFields.Add2`. So I think using `SortFields.Add` should be preferred.

Comment: Ah ok. yes .add is definitely safer and compatible with lower versions

Comment: Its working now, I replaced Add2 by Add. Found this solution in some other forum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that there aren't any missing references on the machine with problems.
If it works on one machine but not another, then there must be something 'wrong' with one machine, or with the copy of the spreadsheet.

Are you using option explicit?

Have you compiled the code?

Copy the sheet from the machine where it works to the one where it doesn't.

Are the versions of Excel 2016 the same?

Maybe the office installation needs a repair.

Personally I would get rid of all those 'actives' and 'selects' and define proper objects to work with.

Comment: Its working now, I replaced Add2 by Add. Found this solution in some other forum. Thanks for your help.