# Can't Execute in Excel 2010 Version

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed the code in excel 2019 version . I cannot execute the code in excel 2010 version which is used by my team members . I have attached the code below , it executes well for me but when others with windows 2010 version execute , it says error.

I have developed the code which compares two sheets ( sheet1 and sheet2 ) and unique records that found in sheet2 are copied and pasted to sheet3.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveDupes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook
    ClearSheet .Worksheets("Steps2")
    FindDupes .Worksheets("Interface"), .Worksheets("Steps"), .Worksheets("Steps2")
End With
End Sub

Sub ClearSheet(ws As Worksheet)
'Clears data (but not header labels) from ws
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = ws.UsedRange
Set rg = rg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, rg.Columns.Count)
rg.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub FindDupes(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet)
'Look for records in ws2 that isn't in ws1. Copy those rows to wsDest.
Dim frmla1 As String, frmla2 As String, frmlaTest As String
Dim rgCopy As Range, rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range, rgTest1 As Range, rgTest2 As Range
Dim n As Long, nCols As Long, nRows As Long
Set rg2 = ws2.Range("C6").CurrentRegion     'C6 must be a cell in data block
nCols = rg2.Columns.Count
nRows = rg2.Rows.Count
Set rg2 = Range(rg2.Cells(2, 1), rg2.Cells(nRows, nCols))

Set rg1 = ws1.Range("C6").CurrentRegion     'C6 must be a cell in data block
Set rg1 = Range(rg1.Cells(2, 1), rg1.Cells(rg1.Rows.Count, nCols))

Set rgTest1 = rg1.Columns(nCols + 1)
frmla1 = ConcatFormulaBuilder(rg1, 2, 4)
rgTest1.Cells(1).FormulaR1C1 = frmla1
rgTest1.FillDown
rgTest1.Formula = rgTest1.Value

Set rgTest2 = rg2.Columns(nCols + 1)
frmla2 = ConcatFormulaBuilder(rg2, 2, 4)
rgTest2.Cells(1).FormulaR1C1 = frmla2
rgTest2.FillDown
rgTest2.Formula = rgTest2.Value

frmlaTest = MatchFormulaBuilder(rgTest1)
rgTest2.Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = frmlaTest
rgTest2.Columns(2).FillDown
rgTest2.Columns(2).Formula = rgTest2.Columns(2).Value

Sorter rgTest2.Columns(2)
n = Application.CountIf(rgTest2.Columns(2), "Unique")
If n > 0 Then
    Set rgCopy = Range(rg2.Cells(1, 1), rg2.Cells(n, nCols))
    wsDest.UsedRange.Cells(2, 1).Resize(n, nCols).Value = rgCopy.Value
End If
rgTest1.EntireColumn.Delete
rgTest2.Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Function ConcatFormulaBuilder(rg As Range, FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long)
Dim frmla As String
Dim i As Long, J As Long
J = rg.Column - 1
For i = FirstCol To LastCol
    frmla = frmla & "& ""|"" &RC" & (i + J)
Next
ConcatFormulaBuilder = "=" & Mid(frmla, 8)
End Function

Function MatchFormulaBuilder(rg As Range)
Dim addr As String
addr = "'" & rg.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
MatchFormulaBuilder = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1]," & addr & ",0)),"""",""Unique"")"
End Function

Sub Sorter(SortColumn As Range)
'Sort target worksheet by SortColumn in alphabetical order
Dim SortRange As Range
Set SortRange = SortColumn.CurrentRegion
With SortColumn.Worksheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=SortColumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange SortRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

It Executes without any error in Excel 2019 but shows error in Excel 2010 .

Comment: What error, at what line?  Also, at a quick look, you're missing a qualifier on the first `Range()`:  `Set rg2 = Range(rg2.Cells(2, 1), rg2.Cells(nRows, nCols))` ...do you mean `Set rg2 = rg2.Range(...)`?  Actually, you do that a lot. You specify the sheet/range in the interior `Cells()`, but not on the outer `Range()`, which I believe will throw an error.

Comment: .Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=SortColumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55872337/edit) instead of adding info in comments

Comment: I would guess that `.Add2` is a new method introduced in later version of excel and is not available in XL2010.  Releated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148316/what-is-add2-for-sortfields

Comment: `SortRange.Sort Key1:=SortColumn, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal` Try this. This will work in all versions of Excel... Even in Excel 2003

Comment: If you try to compile the code in Excel 2010, you'll see that the VBE tells you exactly where the problem(s) is/are. Excel 2019 has a TON of features that don't exist in Excel 2010; if your code is built in 2019 and needs to run on 2010, make sure you only use APIs and members that exist in the 2010 type library.