# Why is my data-sorting macro not performing the sorts in the correct order?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have some very simple VBA code

```
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Stage"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Category"), Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
```

My understanding is that, for example, this mock table

```
    Stage    Category
   1-First   2-Finance
   4-Fourth  2-Finance
   2-Second  3-Operations
   1-First   1-Strategy
```

should be sorted as

```
    Stage    Category
   1-First   1-Strategy
   1-First   2-Finance
   2-Second  3-Operations
   4-Fourth  2-Finance
```

Yet what I am getting when I run the Macro is

```
    Stage    Category
   1-First   1-Strategy
   1-First   2-Finance
   4-Fourth  2-Finance
   2-Second  3-Operations
```

Why is Category taking preference?

Comment: Change both of the ```.add``` to ```.add2``` and see if it works.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148316/what-is-add2-for-sortfields

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing the trick..

Comment: Or maybe `Key1:=` and `Key2:=`

Comment: I'm actually getting an error on that. Are Key1 and Key2 valid options?

Comment: I'm sorry, to be honest I don't know. My way to sort with multiple criteria is something like this : `Set RangeToSort = Range("A1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
RangeToSort.Sort Key1:=RangeToSort.Columns(1), Key2:=RangeToSort.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=Yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me, using your data. Add the `.SetRange` parameter.

```
Sub test()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B5")
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Stage"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Category"), Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, but it wasn't just ```.SetRange``` that did the trick... I added that and it was still broken in the same way. After adding the first line with ```Sort.SortFields.Clear``` we were finally in business. Would love if someone could explain to me what line of code even does...

Comment: @bhbennett3 I could not find an answer in cursory search for why ```Sort.SortFields.Clear``` is needed first, though I swear I found that information once before.  I almost suggested adding that since I have it first in all my sorts, but I really thought ```.add2``` was the main cause, since ```.add2``` is allegedly related to sub-field sorting.  If I ever find why the Clear needs to happen first I'll update you here.